# Junit 4 test inner class in kotlin

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, testing, junit

I use Junit4 and kotlin.

I use the Enclosed for the inner class test.

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.experimental.runners.Enclosed
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(Enclosed::class)
class SampleTest {

    var text = "parent class"

    class Class1 {
        @Test
        fun `print the text`() {
            println(text)
        }
    }

    inner class Class2 {
        @Test
        fun `print the text`() {
            println(text)
        }
    }

}
```

in Class1 and Class2, need the `text` variable.

I use the `inner` for an access child class to parent class.

but I have a problem, the test function is removed and I can't test that. see the photo.

[image]

can I test the inner class in kotlin with Junit4?

Answer (score 3):

`Class1` is a plain nested class that happens to be in `SampleTest`. It's just an organisational thing, your `Class1` instance doesn't have any reference to a `SampleTest` instance, so it can't access `text` (not without being passed an instance explicitly).

If you want a nested class to be able to access an enclosing instance like that, you need to mark it as `inner`, like with `Class2`. That way you can create an instance of `Class2` through an instance of `SampleClass`, like

```
val sample = SampleClass()
val class2 = sample.Class2()
sample.text = "wow!"
class2.`print the text`()
```

You can read about this stuff in [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html) if it's unfamiliar

So yeah, if JUnit constructs a `Class1` instance, it doesn't know what `text` is, since that's an instance variable in some other unrelated class.

And I'm assuming it doesn't know how to create `Class2`, since it requires a `SampleTest` instance to do that. All the examples for [`Enclosed`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/experimental/runners/Enclosed.html) use static nested classes, and like [the Java docs say](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html):

> A static nested class interacts with the instance members of its outer class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class. **In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.**

so that's basically the same as Kotlin's (non-inner) nested classes, like your `Class1`. You probably can't use `inner` classes (not to organise and automatically run tests, anyway)

You probably want to stick `text` in a `companion object` if you're organising your tests in classes (or just a top-level `object` outside of `SampleClass`, or just in the top level of the file if you really want - just somewhere it can be accessed by any other class in a "static" way

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways :

1. use JUnit's `Enclosed` and the `companion object` and don't use the inner class

   ```kotlin
   @RunWith(Enclosed::class)
   class ParentTest {
       companion object {
           var text = "parent class"
       }

       class Class1 {
           @Test
           fun `print the text`() {
               println(text)
           }
       }

       class Class2 {
           @Test
           fun `print the text`() {
               println(text)
           }
       }

   }
   ```
2. use [`NestedRunner`](https://github.com/NitorCreations/CoreComponents/)
3. use [`HierarchicalContextRunner`](https://github.com/bechte/junit-hierarchicalcontextrunner/wiki)